# What is the probability that none of the events happens?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there are 3 events such that:

P(A)=0.20

P(B)=0.10

P(C)=0.40

P(A ∩ B)=0.05

P(A ∩ C)=0.10

P(B ∩ C)=0.03

P(A ∩ B ∩ C)=0.01

What is the probability that none of the events happens?

this is my solution: 1 - (.2 + .1 + .4 + .05 + .1 + .03 + 01) = .11

however, my answer manual says the final answer is .47

am i doing something wrong ? pls help

Comment: The "none of the events" here must refer to events A,B,C.  The computation proceeds by inclusion/exclusion (which phrase is familiar, I hope, from your lessons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want the find probability that at least one of the events happen, and then do $1$ minus that. Using the inclusion-exclusion formula:

$$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(B\cap C)+P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

You have all these values.

Comment: thank you this makes sense. i guess my approach was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**hin**t:$$P(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c)= P((A\cup B\cup C)^c)= 1- P(A\cup B\cup C) = 1- P(A)-P(B)-P(C) + P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap C) + P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B\cap C)=.....$$